# why program is not executing as it suppose to?

Tags: c++, max

I have got a fault in my code, but I do not know what it is.
I go through my list and I want to calculate my maximum, but a bad result comes out.
When the years are consecutive with a difference of 1 year and the height to the year is higher or equal than the year before, I increase the value of maxdb by one.
So I would like to choose the maximum of this sequence when this happen.

But something went wrong because I get the 1 number for my result and you can see that the result have to be 2, because of these :
1992 230,
1993 232,
1994 232

What can be the fault in my code?

```
Input   (year,heigh)               
8                     
1960 208
1960 210
1973 210
1992 230
1993 232
1994 232
2010 238
2011 239
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    int T[N];
    int Mag[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> T[i];
        cin >> Mag[i];
    }

    int maxdb = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        if (T[i + 1] == T[i] && Mag[i] <= Mag[i + 1])
        {
            maxdb++;
        }
           
        cout << maxdb;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int N;...int T[N]; int Mag[N];` -- Well, one fault is that you're not using C++.  This is not valid C++, as arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime variable.  A dynamic array in C++ is achieved by using `std::vector<int> T(N), Mag(N);`

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can slow the execution of the program down to your speed and watch exactly what the computer does with the program as it does it. Typical usage is to step through the program line-by-line and keep an eye out for the unexpected, stuff like the wrong path taken or the wrong value stored. The unexpected is a bug in your program or in your expectations. Either needs to be resolved.

Comment: What does "calculate my maximum" mean? What does "maximum of this sequence" mean? Why does "the result have to be 2"? It is completely unclear how this data should be processed, and there are many different ways to interpret "maximum". Try to pretend that you're talking to someone who has absolutely no idea what this program has to do, and explain what the program needs to calculate. Also, it will also be helpful to actually use valid C++, instead of non-standard C++, also.

Comment: Side note: if two values are intimately related often it is better to bundle them up into a structure and have a container of that structure rather than two containers of the values separately. This is particularly helpful when you need to sort.

Comment: The way you described your code `When the years are consecutive` but the code says `T[i+1] == T[i]` which means `the years are identical`  If you want consecutive replace `T[i+1] == T[i]` with `T[i+1] == T[i]+1`   But keep in mide that the way you are counting means `1992 230, 1993 232, 1994 232` makes maxdb equal 2 but `2010 238, 2011 239` increases it to 3.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it should be two instead of three unless You want the maximum of all the sequence lengths.  But if you do you need two variables - one to keep track of the length of each sequence that you find (resetting it to zero when the sequence ends) and a second variable to keep track of the maximum of the lengths.  Something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/1iVQgeHzH

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for the longest sequence of consecutive years.

Let's clean your code up a bit by growing your two data points into a single chunk of data.

```
struct Info {
    int year;
    int height;
};
```

But let's also overload the `<<` and `>>` operators to make reading in and printing the data easier.

```
struct Info {
    int year;
    int height;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Info& i) {
        in >> i.year >> i.height;
        return in;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Info& i) {
        out << i.year << " " << i.height;
        return out;
    }
};
```

Now, in `main` we'll read an int describing how many data points there will be, and create a `std::vector<Info>` to hold those values.

```
int main() {
    int n;

    std::cout << "Number of lines of info: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<Info> v(n);
}
```

We'll then use a loop to read in the info we need.

```
    for (auto &i : v) {
        std::cin >> i;
    }
```

Since your code works beest when years are sorted, let's do that using `std::sort` and a lambda.

```
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.year < b.year; });
```

We can use another loop to print all of the data, and ensure it sorted.

```
    for (auto &i : v) {
        std::cout << i << endl;
    }
```

But now, the real meat of your problem. As I understand it, you wish to find the longest run of consecutive years. Well, let's keep track of the current run of consecutive years. We'll loop over the vector using an iterator and in this case only go to the next to last item, since we're comparing one `Info` struct against the next one.

If the current year is one less than the next year, we'll increment `current_run`, otherwise we'll zero it out.

```
    int current_run = 0;

    for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end() - 1; iter++) {
        Info cur = *iter;
        Info next = *(iter + 1);

        if (cur.year == next.year - 1) {
            current_run++;
        }
        else {
            current_run = 0;
        }
    }
```

With your sample input, `current_run` will end up being `1`. We need some way to store the `current_run` value before we wipe it out when a streak ends.

So we'll create a `max_run` variable initialized to `0`.

```
    int current_run = 0;
    int max_run = 0;

    for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end() - 1; iter++) {
        Info cur = *iter;
        Info next = *(iter + 1);

        if (cur.year == next.year - 1) {
            current_run++;
        }
        else if (current_run > max_run) {
            max_run = current_run;
            current_run = 0;
        }
        else {
            current_run = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now, with your sample input, the result in `max_run` is `2`.  Putting it all together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Info {
    int year;
    int height;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Info& i) {
        in >> i.year >> i.height;
        return in;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Info& i) {
        out << i.year << " " << i.height;
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n;

    std::cout << "Number of lines of info: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<Info> v(n);

    for (auto &i : v) {
        std::cin >> i;
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.year < b.year; });

    for (auto &i : v) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    int current_run = 0;
    int max_run = 0;

    for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end() - 1; iter++) {
        Info cur = *iter;
        Info next = *(iter + 1);

        if (cur.year == next.year - 1) {
            current_run++;
        }
        else if (current_run > max_run) {
            max_run = current_run;
            current_run = 0;
        }
        else {
            current_run = 0;
        }
    }

    std::cout << max_run << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your input only one case will get if statement true. The first one and the second one both 1960 are equal and second condition 208 <= 210. Only that will work so it will increment from 0 to 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).